# Mongodb: should I use a `foreach` or a `$lookup` to perform an update on `collection1` using data from `collection2` for better performance?

Tags: database, mongodb, join, nosql, database-performance

I have two collections, `collection1` and `collection2` and I need to update all records in `collection1` by decorating them with some corresponding data from `collection2`. To "join" these collections I have an entry `userid` in both collections that I can use to identify matching records.

For better performance, should I use `foreach` or a `$lookup`?

Comment: Im not sure about the entire performance but you would certainly have to send a lot of aditional requests to the database when using `foreach` to fetch the matching entries from `collection2` so network latency and additional overhead might be a thing

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ? What is your collection size ?

Comment: @whoami it is 4.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you use `.find()` & then write back to database, You're reading a set of data from database & iterating over all of those documents using `foreach` & then writing back to database again, If you've a huge dataset to work on then this definitely a time consuming thing & unnecessary impact on both application & database servers, which can also be time consuming as data has to flow through servers & is not preferred to so. Just in case if you had to got this route check [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html) - at least that helps you to write documents in one DB call, but there is a  limitation, it can process only **100K** docs in a go if you send more, then it will internally do chunks & process data - but I've not really tested it with millions of docs.

As you've version `4.2.3`, Starting MongoDB v`4.2` aggregation has a new feature [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html) that can help merge results of aggregation query to another collection, To be in safe point first try to write data to a new collection & if everything looks good write it on `collection1` - at any point have a backup on `collection1`. This could save you sometime & also all the processing do happen in server side (Database side). Apart from this both approaches has read & write mechanism so test your queries are covered with indexes by using [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/index.html). Also consider [aggregation-limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/index.html).

Comment: I have been trying `bulkWrite` in the end with the merging / join logic in PHP. It often ends in `socket error or timeout`. Interesting to know that mongodb implements chunking of the bulk operations internally, because I already implemented chunking in PHP... Anyway, I'm not too familiar with `$merge`, and was just hoping you might have a hunch about which one is better? Which one would you try first `$merge` or `bulkWrite` with the merging logic in php?

Comment: @gen : I guess the chucking part in `.bulkWrite` is done by drivers even though there is an internal option we shouldn't be sending 100K docs to a different server at any go that should be huge on normal servers, What is your collection size ? My suggestion is to try out `$merge`, if you're not ok with MongoDB queries or if your collection size if less in number then try out `bulkWrite`.`$merge` is pretty simple you can easily get through it within 5mins of reading the given doc, prior to adding `$merge` to end of your aggregation query just look thoroughly on what your aggregation returns :-)

Comment: I just had a look at the `$merge` docs, but it seems it doesn't allow JOINs where you have a one-to-many relation, as it seems that the `on` property of `$merge` has to be unique on the the collection that you are merging into... I guess I'll have to stick to `bulkWrite`. Thanks for spelling things out for me, though.

Comment: @gen : Yes fields on which you'll be merging has to be `unique`, if at all `.bulkWrite()` doesn't work for you, You can go ahead with `$merge` or use `$out` to write to a new collection & once your new collection is good, rename `collection1` to `collection1-old` & rename new collection to `collection1` :-)